# JQuery ajax post callback function not executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a quite simple javascript method, which should send an ajax request to a server, and should finally execute a callback function. The problem is that the given callback isn't executed. I also see in the chrome developer tools that the request is executed, and returns the wished JSON. I have also set the Content type to application/json.

Here is the code I have used:

```
this.checkAvailability = function(){
    console.log('Before test');
    $.post('/Roomanizer-Website/Reservation', {
        action: 'checkavailability',
        categoryname: $('#categoryname').val(),
        roomcount: $('#roomcount').val(),
        start: $('#start').val(),
        end: $('#end').val()
    }, function(data){
        console.log('callback');
        console.log(data);
        if(data.available == 'true'){
            $('#start_confirmation').html(data.arrival);
            $('#end_confirmation').html(data.leaving);
            $('#price_confirmation').html(data.price);
            this.nextStep();
        } else {
            alert('There are no free rooms during your chosen period.');
        }
    }, 'json');
};
```

The 'Before Test' is written on the console, but not 'callback'. But as I have already said, the request is executed, and returns the correct JSON:

```
{arrival : '20/06/2012', leaving : '28/06/2012', price: '0.0', available: 'true'}
```

And last i will show the http-header:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/Roomanizer-Website/Reservation
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:97
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:JSESSIONID=AF1302ECA526216D8207F365F6802814
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/Roomanizer-Website/Controller?action=booking
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview URL encoded
action:checkavailability
categoryname:Economy
roomcount:1
start:20/06/2012
end:28/06/2012
Response Headersview source
Content-Length:81
Content-Type:application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date:Mon, 11 Jun 2012 12:19:45 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

Does anybody know hot to solve this issue?

PS: I am using JQuery 1.5.2

Comment: You might use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ instead of `$.post` and implement an error callback.

Comment: Thank you for this input! The json was invalid, so i changed it to:
{"arrival":"20/06/2012","leaving":"27/06/2012","price":"80.0", "available":"true"}

Comment: @DanielRotter Are you aware that you can add your solution as an answer to your own question? Otherwise this question will incorrectly show up in the "unsolved" list. You might also get some votes for it ;-)

Comment: You mean i should answer my own question, and mark this answer as accepted? A bit strange, isn't it?^^

Comment: @DanielRotter Not at all strange. It is the correct solution to the problem and perfectly acceptable [and encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to answer it yourself. It will also help others searching for similar issues in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, as it seems single quotes are not acceptable for the JSON-Parser, so I changed the returning string to

```
{"arrival":"20/06/2012","leaving":"27/06/2012","price":"80.0", "available":"true"}
```